# Цикл в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, циклы

Есть программа,я ввожу с клавиатуры символ,после этого мне выводится его двоичный код(перевод ASII кода символа в двоичный формат),после этого в числе считается количество единичных бит и записывается в переменную counter,далее мне нужно продолжить ввод следующего символа и сделать тоже самое,что и с первым(вывести его двоичный код и посчитать количество единичных бит в нем).

С первым символом программа работает без проблем,с последующими мне не выводиться ни правильное число в двоичном формате,подсчет единичных бит тоже не работает.Я подозреваю,что проблема в том,что я перехожу в начало программы(с помощью метки) и что-то остается с предыдущего выполнения,пробовал обнулить регистры,все равно ничего не получается.

Как перейти в начало программы,чтоб при этом она работала с новым символом?Тоесть как вернуть все регистры и переменные,кроме counter,в исходное положение?

```
.8086
.model small
.stack 200h
DATA SEGMENT    
    counter dw 0
    STR1 DB "BINARY NUMBER IS : $"
    STR2 DB "DECIMAL NUMBER IS : $"
    BSTR DB 20 DUP("$")
    RSTR DB 20 DUP("$")
    NEWLINE DB 13,10,"$"
    CNT DB 0
    N DB 2
    H DB 16
    D DB 10H
    NUM DB ?
    SNUM DB ?
    HNUM DB 0H

  DATA ENDS
  CODE SEGMENT
      ASSUME CS:CODE,DS:DATA 
  START:  

    MOV AX,DATA
    MOV DS,AX
    xor ax,ax 

    ;
    EchoLoop:  
    mov HNUM,0h

    xor ax,ax
    xor al,al
    xor ah,ah
    xor bx,bx 
    xor dx,dx
    ;xor cx,cx
    xor dh,dh
    xor dl,dl


    mov ah,1
    int 21h
    cmp al,13 ;Если символ Enter,выходим
    jz EchoDone
    mov HNUM,al
    ;Перевод из 16 в нужный нам формат------------------------------
    ;CONVERT HEXA TO DECIMAL

    MOV CX,00
    MOV DX,00

    L6:MOV AX,00
    MOV AL,HNUM
    DIV D
    MOV HNUM,AL

    MOV BX,AX
    MOV CL,CNT
    MOV AX,1
    L5: CMP CL,00
        JE L7
        MUL H
        SUB CL,1
        JMP L5    
   L7: MUL BH
    ADD DX,AX
    ADD CNT,1
    CMP HNUM,0
    JG L6
    MOV NUM,DL


    ;CONVERT DECIMAL TO BINARY
    LEA SI,BSTR
    LEA DI,RSTR
L1: MOV AX,00
    MOV AL,NUM
    DIV N
    ADD AH,30H
    MOV BYTE PTR[SI],AH
    INC SI
    MOV NUM,AL
    CMP AL,0
    JG L1

    DEC SI

 L2:MOV BL,BYTE PTR[SI]
    MOV BYTE PTR[DI],BL
    DEC SI
    INC DI
    CMP SI,0
    JNE L2
 ;Перевод из 16 в нужный нам формат------------------------------
    ;MOV AH,09H
    ;LEA DX,STR1
    ;INT 21H



    MOV AH,09H
    LEA DX,RSTR
    INT 21H

    xor si,si        
    xor bx,bx 

    mov cx,20
    ;Подсчет единичных бит
    cycle:
    inc si
    cmp RSTR[si-1],'1'
    jz metka2
    loop cycle       


    jmp EchoLoop ;Переход на начало
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H    


    metka2:
    inc counter  ;schetchik edinichnuh bit
    loop cycle   

    EchoDone:
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h

    CODE ENDS
    END START
```

На картинке результат работы программы:ввожу символ а,мне выводит его двоичный код,ввожу символ b,выводит мусорное значение.

[image: Результат работы]

На 2 картинке:ввожу символ с,мне выводит его двоичный код,ввожу символ e,опять выводит мусор.

[image: Результат2]

Comment: Как минимум metka2 поднимите выше. Если по ней loop не отработает - программа сразу завершится. Это так и задумано ?

Comment: И кстати биты можно было бы считать одновременно с подготовкой в двоичном виде - оно как то практичнее

Comment: да,так и задумано,я плохо знаю асм,пишу как могу

Comment: Но как только вы заканчиваете считать биты то loop cycle который после metla2 не уходит на цикл и выполняется следующая за ним команда - выход из программы

Comment: он уходит на цикл,я в отладчике это четко вижу

Comment: А когда 20 итераций подсчета закончится что проиходит. Цикл же не вечен